# Polyhedronizing a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I am looking to polyhedronize an arbitrary set of points, $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. That is to say, I want to construct a polyhedron whose set of vertices is exactly $S$.

I was reading the following paper:

http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/publications/bbdlink.pdf

On page 10 it states the following:

Theorem:

> A set of points $S$ in space admits a monotonic polyhedronization that be obtained in $O(n \text{log} n)$ time.

In the paper, the set of points in $S$ is also assumed to be in general position.

The paper then goes on to give the proof.

Proof:

> First compute the convex hull $CH(S)$ of $S$. If no points of $S$ lie inside the convex hull we are done because the polyhedron $CH(S)$ is a monotonic polyhedron. Otherwise, the shadow boundary of the convex hull of $S$, in other words the set of edges common to $CH_{L}(S)$ and $CH_{U}(S)$. Let $S_{U}$ be the subset of points in $S$ which are not vertices of $CH_{L}(S)$. Triangulate in any way the projection of the set $S_{U} \cup B$ on the $xy$-plane, and lift each triangle to the points that projected onto its vertices. By gluing along $B$ this terrain with $CH_{L}(S)$ we obtain the desired monotonic polyhedron.
>   Computing the convex hull and constructing a triangulation of the projected points can be done in time $O(n \text{log} n)$, which is the overall running time as the lifting step only requires $O(n)$ times.

My first question is can we still achieve $O(n \text{log} n)$ time if we do not require that the points of $S$ be in general position? If we can then can we use the same construction for the polyhedron?

Comment: Polyhedronize is a terribly horrible word...

Comment: Assuming the points are in general position is something of a weak condition.  If we were allowed a slight perturbation of the points in $S$, then we could assure that this is the case.  On the other hand suppose that the points $S$ are given lying in a straight line.  In that case no polyhedron could have those points as its vertices.  So, while we cannot dispense entirely with the assumption of "general position", in practice it is not a burdensome restriction.

Comment: How would you apply it to the set of  points that contains the vertices of the unit cube and a point in the center of the cube? I imagine that the polyhedron that should be created should have all the edges of a regular cube except one of the faces has all its vertices also connected to the point in the center of the cube, but is this result always guaranteed for any perturbation.

Comment: From what you sketched, you start with the cube (as the convex hull of points), then you pick one side to form a "dimple" with the center of the cube.  You are free to choose which side will have this indentation, so the solution is not unique.  The result, not being unique, is not "always guaranteed" to be the same whether we allow perturbations or not.

Comment: What I mean is that when you project $S_{U} \cup B$ and triangulate it there is some ambiguity to where you lift the triangles to since there is degeneracy in the $xy$-plane. If we lift the triangles to only one of the faces and to the point in the center, then of course we will get the result you described and the face that is chosen is not always the same. However what if two triangles lift to vertices such that the plane just forms a plane that cuts through the diagonal of the cube?